# Could not decode result data

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I have an issue when trying deploy contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: ISC
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

contract SimpleStorage {
uint256 favoriteNumber;

struct People {
    uint256 favoriteNumber;
    string name;
}

// uint256[] public anArray;
People[] public people;

mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber;

function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
    favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
}

function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
    return favoriteNumber;
}

function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
    people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
    nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
}
```

deploy.js

```
const { ethers, run } = require("hardhat");


async function main() {
  const contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleStorage");
  console.log("Deploying contract...");
  const deploy = await contract.deploy();
  console.log(`Deployed contract to ${contract.address}`);

  const currentValue = await deploy.retrieve()
  console.log(`Current Value is: ${currentValue}`)

  // verify contract
  await verify(deploy.address, []);

  // update current value
  const transactionReponse = await deploy.store(7);
  await transactionReponse.wait(1);
  const updatedValue = await deploy.retrieve();
  console.log(`Updated value now is ${updatedValue}`);
}

async function verify(contractAddress, arg) {
  console.log("verifying...");
  await run("verify:verify", {
    address: contractAddress,
    constructorArguments: arg,
  });
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

hardhat.config.js

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify");


/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "goerli",
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: process.env.RPC_URL_GOERLI,
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
  },
  solidity: "0.8.20",
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  }
};
```

Well, the issue itself

```
Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "retrieve", "signature": "retrieve()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.8.1)
code: 'BAD_DATA',
  value: '0x',
  info: { method: 'retrieve', signature: 'retrieve()' },
  shortMessage: 'could not decode result data'
```

Comment: That error message usually indicates the call to `retrieve()` failed. It could be that the contract hasn't deployed correctly, or the call is being execute before it is mined.

Comment: How can i fixed that problem?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you need to add  `await deploy.deployed()` before calling `retrieve`. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77153913/ethers-function-not-found.